# customize django's admin: how to place stylesheet where you want it belong?

Tags: django-admin

I tried to customize django's admin css....but I'm stuck ....i did find a lot of similar discussions here...still I'm not clear... here is what I see...

In base.html, we have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% load adminmedia %}{% admin_media_prefix %}css/base.css{% endblock %}"
```

the line resolves to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/base.css">
```

in the installed admin, base.html is originally located in

C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin

to customize the admin app, I copied admin\templates\admin
to my project templates directory. And then I copied all the C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\media to my project as PROJECT_ROOT\media.

I hope

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/base.css">
```

will use PROJECT_ROOT\media\ for css.....

However, django still uses C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\media ....

could some one explain why?

Further, what I need to do to let  href="/media/css/base.css"  use PROJECT_ROOT\media\?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the URL for your admin media is configured in the settings for [ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admin-media-prefix):

> ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX
>
> Default: '/media/'
>
> The URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images used by the Django administrative interface. Make sure to use a trailing slash, and to have this be different from the MEDIA_URL setting (since the same URL cannot be mapped onto two different sets of files).

Also, if you're using django's development server, see the docs on [How to serve static files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/):

> If you just need to serve the admin media from a nonstandard location, see the --adminmedia parameter to runserver.